Компилятор котлина не распознает ссылку 'kotlinx'
Пытаюсь разбираться с корутинами на котлине. В IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 создаю новый проект на котлине со сборкой в Gradle( в качестве Gradle DSL пробовал и 'Kotlin' и 'Groovy').
В строке kt-файла при наборе строки
import kotlinx.coroutines.* 

'kotlinx' выделяется красным,
и, соответственно, при сборке проекта компилятор выкатывает ошибку:
Unresolved reference 'kotlinx'

Начал с того, что в dependencies {} вносил строку
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:<номер версии>"

или
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:<номер версии>"

, причем пытался играться с разными версиями.
Также пытался убирать/добавлять в проект и модуль соответствующие библиотеки типа:
org.jetbrains.kotlinx\kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm*
и прочие - ошибка не исчезала!
Причем, import kotlin.coroutines (т.е. без 'x') прокатывает на ура.
В общем, дорог хороший совет...

Summarising the talk, I send my problem to Intellij IDEA HELP(by form https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731)
and developers informed me ...
1.Necessary to include to dependencies {} such string:
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0")


Make sure that you use the latest Kotlin version:
plugins {
    // For build.gradle.kts (Kotlin DSL)
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.0"

    // For build.gradle (Groovy DSL)
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "2.0.0"
}


Make sure that you have mavenCentral() in the list of repositories:
(for Kotlin DSL - in "settings.gradle.kts", 
 for Groovy DSL - in "build.gradle" ):
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }


Don't forget (IMPORTANT!) to sync gradle files with projects:
(for Kotlin DSL - in "settings.gradle.kts", 
 Click <ctrl+shift+A> and perform 
"Sync All Gradle Projects"



RESULT: My problem was fixed!
